# Designing a REST API: setting business logic error codes in http headers or within the response payload

Tags: rest, http-response

I am designing a REST api backend that is meant to be consumed by a javascript front-end.

I am not sure how to communicate server-side business logic errors (e.g. a user trying to retrieve his password with an unknown email, etc.) to the front-end.

After setting a 40x status code on the response, I need to add further detail about the error and I am hesitating between two options:

1. Setting custom HTTP headers in the response (e.g. `X-Unknow-Email`)
2. Setting a JSON in the HTTP response payload with the corresponding error code

Can anyone having already being exposed to designing REST APIs please tell me what the pros and cons are for the two solutions being considered above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that option 2 makes it easier to understand what happened.  The client can know to look in the body for a message, which is the usual place information is found. In your option 1, not only would the client need to know to look at the headers (which is more work in many rest client libraries), it would also have to know *which* headers to look for.  In option 2, if need be, you can pass the string message to the user and let them figure out what it means.  I think it is safe to assume that if you return an error code (non-2XX), then the client will not expect an entity in the response body, so it is ok to replace that with the message.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this, in my experience, is to describe a universal error structure for your API. Something like this might suffice:

```
{
  "errorCategory": "Authentication/Authorization",
  "errorMessage": "Unknown email provided as part of authentication",
  "errorDetailURL": "http://api.company.com/documentation/email_auth_error.html",
  "errorId": "some-kind-of-identifer"
}
```

This allows you to provide a category (which is not going to change, and thus is useful for client code), a message (which may change, and is best for manual auditing and testing), a more detailed URL (which can be used to provide documentation on how to address specific errors, without wasting bandwidth), and an ID for *this instance* of the error, which can be provided to your support team if the client believes it is a bogus error.

This can be used in both `40x` and `50x` errors, and *must be consistent*.